# Find Positions of Multiple Occurrences of a Character in a String

Tags: java, indexing

If I have a string `line = "XYZTGEXGXRX"`, `line.indexOf("X");` returns the index of the first `"X"` that is contained in that string.

What I want to know, is what what would allow me to get the second `"X"`, or any occurrence of `"X"` after that?

Comment: What language are you looking for a solution in?  C#, Java, JavaScript... The answer would be different depending on choice of language.

Comment: Sorry about that, its Java!

Comment: possible duplicate of [index of string in multiple positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595501/index-of-string-in-multiple-positions)

Answer (score 2):

Answer can be found here:
[Java indexOf method for multiple matches in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988050/java-indexof-method-for-multiple-matches-in-string)

There is a second parameter for indexOf which sets a start parameter.
This code example prints all indices of x

```
i = str.indexOf('x');
while(i >= 0) {
     System.out.println(i);
     i = str.indexOf('x', i+1);
}
```